# Upgrade existing umbraco project with version 4.8.1 to latest version 7.5.3

Tags: content-management-system, version, umbraco, upgrade, umbraco-contour

I want to upgrade my existing umbraco project with version 4.8.1 to latest version 7.5.3, but i don't know the exact way, whether to convert incremental step by step (from 4.8.1 to 4.10.X, 4.10.X to 4.11.X and so on..) or directly to version 7.5.3, Please give me the proper solution that let me upgrade my existing versioned umbraco project to latest version of umbraco.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have done a couple of these now, one of them on a very large site. I would definitely upgrade v4 incrementally to each minor revision because the upgrade process was not as reliable as it is now and there is potentially breaking changes as well as a number of files to remove. Read ahead about the [Version specific upgrades](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Upgrading/version-specific) found on the Our Umbraco site.

Luckily for you, there are Nuget packages all the way back to the version you are starting from so I would take advantage of that and upgrade the package at each step and commit your changes to your source code repository and tag them before moving on to the next. It helps when you come to repeat the process on your production site.

So, my first attempted upgrade path would probably be as follows:

4.8.1 > 4.9.1 > 4.10.1.1 > 4.11.10 > 6.2.6 > 7.5.x

One of the biggest gotchas I found was reading the release notes and making sure you REMOVE all of the files that are no longer required and detailed in the release notes.

Compared to how it used to be there is now a lot more information around to help you if and when you get stuck.

Comment: Hi, Can you please specify the steps i can go through to upgrade umbraco ?, I tried upgrading 4.8.1 to 4.9.1 through nuget package, but after that it starts from scratch, i want to upgrade the project whether by incrementally to each minor version or directly to 7.5.4, Thanks btw !

Comment: When you upgrade, use beyond compare to merge files on an individual basis. Use source control to undo anything nuget did that you didn't want. This is all especially important for the /config and web.config

The most tricky part of upgrades is upgrading the packages. If a package becomes obsolete, sometimes, you can fix the package by contributing to it if it is open source. Sometimes, you try to replace the package with something equivalent. Other times, you can attempt some sort of migration. I'd do an audit before you start, so you know what you are getting into.

Comment: Hi, I have successfully upgraded to umbraco version - 4.11.10 using nuget package, but not able to upgrade to version - 6.0.0 or more using nuget package, so i want the upgrade steps either through nuget package or any other way - with changes in database, please help me to resolve this problem, Thanks :)

Comment: @Dharmesh You give no details about WHY you can't upgrade to v6.0.0.

Comment: Hi @ProNotion, I have upgraded successfully to version 6.0.0, Thanks for your help and support. There was trouble with dll conflicts and db changes in enhancement in v6.0.0, I replaced those dlls with required version and also added some new tables and new fields in database by comparing it with downloaded v6.0.0 zip package. 

But I was having a custom section in existing project and now when i click on that custom section, tree items in that custom section not loading, Please help if you have any idea, Thanks :)

Comment: That's a different question and so I would ask it as such rather than using this existing one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way of doing this kind of upgrade. It all depends how complex was your solution and what you've built at top of Umbraco itself. I suggest you to create a backup of everything and just give it a shot to do update straight from one to the latest version. You can use nuget for this if you're familiar with Visual Studio (it will create backups for configuration files and merge it automatically for you).

You can also watch Per Ploug's session from this year Codegarden. It has a lot of tips and tricks for all people who wants to upgrade their old sites. Video is available here: https://video.twentythree.net/migrating-mom-to-uaas. Can't remember, but it may be possible that you will need to update to v6.x something to be able to process further directly to 7.x. But create backups and play with it - it's my opinion and suggestion :)

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thanks for answering my question ! I tried the way you specified, directly by installing umbraco latest version using nuget package UmbracoCms 7.5.4, but i'm getting error like "Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0" or like "Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Helpers" or like "Could not load file or assembly system.web.webPages.razor", Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Upgrading directly from 4.x to 7.5.x will most certainly fail. There are far too many breaking changes between those versions. You will at least need upgrade to 6.2.6 before you upgrade to 7.2.5. One of the problems is that some of the upgrades will make changes to the database schema. If you try to skip too far, these upgrades will probably fail. I'd go with ProNotion's suggestion of upgrades.

Comment: Hi, I have successfully upgraded to umbraco version - 4.11.10 using nuget package, but not able to upgrade to version - 6.0.0 or more using nuget package, so i want the upgrade steps either through nuget package or any other way - with changes in database, please help me to resolve this problem, Thanks :)